# Make ANT Java target work like Java command

Tags: java, ant

These are the commands that I am trying to emulate in Ant:

```
cd "../Reinforcement Learning Task Generator"
java -cp "bin;../Utilities/bin;../Reinforcement Learning/bin" edu.uky.ai.rl.Generate
```

They work as expected.

Here is my Ant build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<project name="Builds" default="generate_rl">
    <target name="generate_rl">
        <java
            classname="edu.uky.ai.rl.Generate"
            dir="../Reinforcement Learning Task Generator"
            fork="true"
        >
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="bin"/>
                <pathelement path="../Utilities/bin"/>
                <pathelement path="../Reinforcement Learning/bin"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

I am getting "Error: Could not find or load main class edu.uky.ai.rl.Generate"

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This also does not work, with the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<project name="Builds" default="generate_rl">
    <target name="generate_rl">
        <java
            classname="edu.uky.ai.rl.Generate"
            dir="../Reinforcement Learning Task Generator"
            classpath="bin;../Utilities/bin;../Reinforcement Learning/bin"
            fork="true"
        >
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Build time, execution time? What command are you using?

Comment: Execution time. I am using Eclipse, so I'm not entirely sure what command it's using.

Answer (score 1):

ant proceeds in the following order:

1. Convert all path entries in ant structures such as `<classpath><pathelement>`, filling in variables and such, and **resolving them to absolute paths**.
2. It will *then* ask the OS to start an external app. Which so happens to be `java.exe`. Like any OS app, the launching app passes [A] the arguments, [B] any environment table modifications, [C] can provide sysin, sysout, and syserr, and [D] **its working directory**. The `dir` option modifies that last one. It has *nothing* to do with where ant looks for those `<pathelement>` items.

Hence, why `dir="foo"` and then a bunch of `<pathelement>` refs that are relative to `foo` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to have been with the `dir` attribute. This configuration worked, though it seems like it should be equivalent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<project name="Builds" default="generate_rl">
    <target name="generate_rl">
        <java
            classname="edu.uky.ai.rl.Generate"
            fork="true"
        >
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="../Reinforcement Learning Task Generator/bin"/>
                <pathelement path="../Utilities/bin"/>
                <pathelement path="../Reinforcement Learning/bin"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```